# Module not found error in nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to run this code to try and create new users for my mongoose database. However, whenever I try to start my server, I am getting an error that says

> Error: Cannot find module '../models/registeruser'

in my terminal. I've tried to fix the issue, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have my code below, as well as a screenshot of my directory structure with the files in each folder visible. Can anyone help me fix it? Thanks!

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Register</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Enter the following information</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/executive/create">
        <label>Enter Your Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" required>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" required>
        <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Enter a username" required>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Register User">
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**executive.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var siteController = require('../controllers/siteController');

router.get('/create', siteController.registerusercreate);

module.exports = router;
```

**registeruser.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    userName: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**siteController.js**

```
var User = require('../models/registeruser');

exports.registerusercreate = function (req, res) {
    let user = new User(
        {
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            userName: req.body.userName,
            email: req.body.email
        }
    );

    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log("Item Saved Successfully!");
    })
};
```

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var executiveRouter = require('./routes/executive'); 

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dev_db_url = 'mongodb://username:<password@ds042908.mlab.com:42908/users'
var mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/executive', executiveRouter);  // Add catalog routes to middleware chain.

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of my file directory with all files]

Comment: can you add your directory structure??

Comment: I have a main folder titled booksite. Inside this I have a folder titled site. Inside this folder I have app.js, and folders titled controllers, models, routes, views. Inside the controllers folder, I have siteController.js. Inside the models folder, I have registermodel.js. Inside the routes folder, I have executive.js. Inside the views folder, I have index.ejs.

Comment: Double check the path, file and folder names

Comment: Please, share the full console logs and directory structure snapshot as there could be some spelling error.

Comment: In my post, I added a screenshot of the directory structure with all files in each folder visible.

Comment: Yes, there is spelling error in model file. You have named it "regsiteruser.js" Correct that and you are good to go. Please, accept my answer as it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is spelling error in model file. You have named it "regsiteruser.js" Correct that and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your executive.js, you have imported the siteController as usernameController but you are using siteController.registerusercreate to call the function. Try fixing the issue and can you post a screenshot of your directory structure with all the folders open?

Comment: I added a screenshot to the post with the directory structure

Comment: Your registeruser.js file is named regsiteuser.js. Hope that helps!